# Elasticsearch returning to the same page with status 302

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch in one of my rails app, and it's seems to work, but most of the time when a user search for there Tags or Posts or Users, it does not return the result instead return back to the search page.I tried finding the prob in my setup, but everything looks pretty good.

**Server Report**

```
2017-09-03T06:35:47.787828+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/autocomplete.json/?term=kol" host=www.wewrite.in request_id=8b55bddf-04e7-4512-9063-2f34e7363aa5 fwd="47.15.7.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=83ms status=304 bytes=647 protocol=http
2017-09-03T06:35:47.996239+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered api/search_autocomplete/index.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:47.996592+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 80ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:47.998254+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/autocomplete.json/?term=kolk" host=www.wewrite.in request_id=0179c693-8175-4347-b11a-299a9871a90e fwd="47.15.7.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=88ms status=304 bytes=647 protocol=http
2017-09-03T06:35:49.438727+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/autocomplete.json/?term=kolka" host=www.wewrite.in request_id=e9f90b80-5804-4606-9495-1d87e4002935 fwd="47.15.7.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=49ms status=304 bytes=647 protocol=http
2017-09-03T06:35:49.391318+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/api/autocomplete.json/?term=kolka" for 47.15.7.112 at 2017-09-03 06:35:49 +0000
2017-09-03T06:35:49.396815+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by API::SearchAutocompleteController#index as JSON
2017-09-03T06:35:49.396866+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"term"=>"kolka"}
2017-09-03T06:35:49.436864+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered api/search_autocomplete/index.json.jbuilder (0.3ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:49.436940+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:49.599323+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/api/autocomplete.json/?term=kolkat" for 47.15.7.112 at 2017-09-03 06:35:49 +0000
2017-09-03T06:35:49.604309+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by API::SearchAutocompleteController#index as JSON
2017-09-03T06:35:49.604366+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"term"=>"kolkat"}
2017-09-03T06:35:49.636210+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered api/search_autocomplete/index.json.jbuilder (0.3ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:49.636426+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 1.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:49.654968+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/autocomplete.json/?term=kolkat" host=www.wewrite.in request_id=e9b53eb5-6dec-4c28-b4c7-69ae0489f10e fwd="47.15.7.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=58ms status=304 bytes=647 protocol=http
2017-09-03T06:35:49.884801+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/autocomplete.json/?term=kolkata" host=www.wewrite.in request_id=ca90c57e-0113-4e8c-8e71-c11d4d94fae3 fwd="47.15.7.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=51ms status=304 bytes=647 protocol=http
2017-09-03T06:35:49.835979+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/api/autocomplete.json/?term=kolkata" for 47.15.7.112 at 2017-09-03 06:35:49 +0000
2017-09-03T06:35:49.844152+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"term"=>"kolkata"}
2017-09-03T06:35:49.883442+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:49.844076+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by API::SearchAutocompleteController#index as JSON
2017-09-03T06:35:49.883151+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered api/search_autocomplete/index.json.jbuilder (0.6ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:50.541060+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SearchController#show as HTML
2017-09-03T06:35:50.541986+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "button"=>"", "search"=>{"q"=>"kolkata"}}
2017-09-03T06:35:50.535308+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/search?utf8=%E2%88%9A&button=&search%5Bq%5D=kolkata" for 47.15.7.112 at 2017-09-03 06:35:50 +0000
2017-09-03T06:35:50.543150+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://www.wewrite.in/search?q=kolkata
2017-09-03T06:35:50.543623+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:50.543462+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as :beautify_url rendered or redirected
2017-09-03T06:35:50.545362+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/search?utf8=%E2%88%9A&button=&search%5Bq%5D=kolkata" host=www.wewrite.in request_id=20b472c5-be7b-40c4-8af3-df71e654ad21 fwd="47.15.7.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=302 bytes=802 protocol=http
2017-09-03T06:35:51.051440+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/search?q=kolkata" for 47.15.7.112 at 2017-09-03 06:35:51 +0000
2017-09-03T06:35:51.059982+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SearchController#show as HTML
2017-09-03T06:35:51.060242+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"q"=>"kolkata"}
2017-09-03T06:35:51.081779+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE 1=0
2017-09-03T06:35:51.096921+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE 1=0
2017-09-03T06:35:51.121114+00:00 app[web.1]:   Tag Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE 1=0
2017-09-03T06:35:51.121604+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered search/show.html.erb within layouts/simple (16.5ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:51.125759+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_overlay.html.erb (1.3ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:51.128360+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_simple_header.html.erb (1.8ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:51.128666+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_alert_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:51.129082+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 69ms (Views: 29.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
2017-09-03T06:35:51.131165+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/search?q=kolkata" host=www.wewrite.in request_id=e64f7d97-210f-4b5e-abef-4d4be2e36550 fwd="47.15.7.112" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=81ms status=200 bytes=4905 protocol=http
2017-09-03T06:36:38.802403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bq%5D=kolkata" host=www.wewrite.in request_id=d153226f-1daf-4e64-818a-edc1f0c1be28 fwd="47.15.7.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=302 bytes=802 protocol=http
2017-09-03T06:36:38.796142+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bq%5D=kolkata" for 47.15.7.112 at 2017-09-03 06:36:38 +0000
2017-09-03T06:36:38.799614+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SearchController#show as HTML
2017-09-03T06:36:38.799682+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>{"q"=>"kolkata"}}
2017-09-03T06:36:38.800756+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://www.wewrite.in/search?q=kolkata
2017-09-03T06:36:38.800920+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as :beautify_url rendered or redirected
2017-09-03T06:36:38.801078+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-09-03T06:36:39.363498+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/search?q=kolkata" host=www.wewrite.in request_id=6f4fae0f-539c-4798-9cd5-7455828dc9bd fwd="47.15.7.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=54ms status=200 bytes=4905 protocol=http
2017-09-03T06:36:39.310111+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/search?q=kolkata" for 47.15.7.112 at 2017-09-03 06:36:39 +0000
2017-09-03T06:36:39.313029+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SearchController#show as HTML
2017-09-03T06:36:39.313056+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"q"=>"kolkata"}
2017-09-03T06:36:39.329892+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE 1=0
2017-09-03T06:36:39.342708+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE 1=0
2017-09-03T06:36:39.358607+00:00 app[web.1]:   Tag Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE 1=0
2017-09-03T06:36:39.358879+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered search/show.html.erb within layouts/simple (15.4ms)
2017-09-03T06:36:39.361251+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_overlay.html.erb (0.7ms)
2017-09-03T06:36:39.361253+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_simple_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
2017-09-03T06:36:39.361461+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_alert_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
2017-09-03T06:36:39.361709+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 49ms (Views: 17.3ms | ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
```

**search controller**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  before_action :beautify_url
  layout "simple"

  def show
    @post_records = Post.search(query_term).paginate(page: params[:page]).records
    @posts = @post_records.to_a.select { |post| post.published? }
    @users = User.search(query_term).records.to_a
    @tags = Tag.search(query_term).records
  end

  def users
    @users = User.search(query_term).records.to_a
  end

  private

    def beautify_url
      if params[:search].present?
        case params[:action]
        when "show"
          redirect_to search_url(q: params[:search][:q])
        when "users"
          redirect_to search_users_url(q: params[:search][:q])
        end
      end
    end

    def query_term
      params[:q] || ''
    end
end
```

**elasticsearch_index_job.rb**

```
class ElasticsearchIndexJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :elasticsearch

  def perform(operation, searchable_class, searchable_id)
    if operation =~ /index|delete/
      self.send(operation, searchable_class, searchable_id)
    else
      logger.warn "PostIndexJob cannot process #{operation}"
    end
  end

  private

    def index(searchable_class, searchable_id)
      searchable = searchable_class.constantize.find_by(id: searchable_id)
      searchable.__elasticsearch__.index_document if searchable.present?
    end

    def delete(searchable_class, searchable_id)
      client = searchable_class.constantize.__elasticsearch__.client
      client.delete index: searchable_class.underscore.downcase.pluralize, 
                    type: searchable_class.underscore.downcase, 
                    id: searchable_id
    end
end
```

**search show page**

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 large-searchbar">
      <%= form_for :search, url: search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
        <%= f.search_field :q, value: params[:q], placeholder: 'Search The App', autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'off', onfocus: "this.value = this.value;" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="search-filter-links">
        <div class="active filter-link">
          <%= link_to search_path(q: params[:q]) do %>
            All <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="filter-link"><%= link_to 'People', search_users_path(q: params[:q]) %></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6" data-animation="fadeInUp-fadeOutDown">
      <% if @posts.any? %>
        <div data-behavior="endless-scroll">
          <h4 class="small-heading border-top">Stories</h4>
          <%= render @posts %>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          <%= will_paginate @post_records %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <aside class="col-md-4" data-animation="fadeInUp-fadeOutDown">
      <% if @tags.any? %>
        <h4 class="small-heading border-top">Topics</h4>
        <%= react_component('TagList', { tags: @tags }, { prerender: true }) %>
      <% end %>
      <% if @users.any? %>
        <h4 class="small-heading border-top">People</h4>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
          <%= render partial: 'search/user_card', locals: { user: user } %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </aside>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You got 302 because you are redirecting user to the other page(with beautiful url). What exactly is your problem? The page is not displayed after redirect? If yes, then attach also log of the second request.

Comment: @unkmas the page do redirect but doesn't show the result of the search...i have updated the logs, please do have a look.

Comment: Everything seems ok. Anyways, it is a bit strange, that you selecting published posts after search - you may have empty result, if none of the posts, returned from elastic is published.